# std::ws vs. std::skipws in C++

Tags: c++, buffer

I'll start with a short piece of code to explain my question:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    int val;
    string s;
    
    std::cin >> val;
    std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s);

    std::cout << val << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I understand that using `std::cin >> val` will leave a newline character in the buffer.
If `std::getline(std::cin, s)` is used afterwards, it's simply going to skip the input because it'll capture that whitespace from `cin`, but if we do `std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s)`, it should work as expected as the `std::ws` is going to consume all the leading whitespace.

Now my question is, there's also such a thing as `std::skipws` which should be doing the same thing from what I understand (`std::getline(std::cin >> std::skipws, s);`), but that is either incorrect because using it still skips the input, or I am using it wrong.

- Why does `std::skipws` not work in this case?
- What's the difference between `std::ws` and `std::skipws`?
- When should we use `std::skipws` over `std::ws`?
- Why do we have 2 implementations of the same thing? Both are supposed to get rid of whitespaces (as per my current understanding)

Comment: Bear in mind `skipws` is set by default. You don't really have to choose to use it, rather choose when to explicitly disable it.

Comment: Re: "it's simply going to skip the input" -- that's not what actually happens. As you say, it sees the newline, and that terminates that read operation. The input that you typed is still there, and will be seen by a subsequent read operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::skipws` (and `std::noskipws`) only apply to *formatted* input, ie `operator>>`, which uses the stream's `sentry` class (the `sentry` is the one doing the actual skipping). They have no effect on *unformatted* input, like `std::getline()`, which don't use the `sentry`. They set/clear the stream's inner `skipws` flag, which stays in effect for all subsequent *formatted* reads until explicitly changed, that flag is not reset after each read, like some other flags are. Each time the `sentry` is created during a *formatted* read, it looks at the current `skipws` flag and acts accordingly.

`std::ws` unconditionally reads whitespace from an input stream. It is used on a per-read basis only.  It is ideal for use with *unformatted* input when you do want to skip whitespace sometimes, but not always.

Comment: In this case, would there ever be a situation when `std::skipws` would be used over `std::ws`, because `std::ws` will always/unconditionally work, while `std::skipws` will only work on _formatted_ input.

Comment: @HarshitJindal `skipws` only works on *formatted* input

Comment: I understand. I accidentally wrote _unformatted_ instead of _formatted_ in my last comment. I've corrected it. So why would we want to use `std::skipws` over `std::ws`, if `std::skipws` only works on _formatted_ input while `std::ws` works on _all_ inputs

Comment: Thank you, this answers all of the points in my question. Marking it as the correct answer